# understand limits of integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

can someone tell me how can I understand the integration limits in this triple integral and the reason behind it ?
assume that I can't draw this 3 dimension domain.
thank you !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcSPF.png)

Comment: What triple integral?

Comment: sorry now it is in the post

Comment: You can’t draw this domain, but you can write it with latex/mathjax, the triple integral included, so we don’t need a link to an image...

Comment: how can I use latex here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the reason behind it".

By looking at the definition of $\Omega$, the condition $x² \leq y \leq x$ tells you that $0 \leq x \leq 1$ (otherwise it is not possible that $x² \leq x$). After you have found the bounds for $x$ you can write the integrals using the bounds for $y$ and $z$ given:

$$\int_\Omega (x+2y) dxdydz = \int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_{x²}^x (x+2y) dydzdx$$

assuming that you are allowed to interchange the integral signs.

Edit: If the order of the integration has to be maintained, you have to adapt the inequalities a little bit: We have $0 \leq z \leq x$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1$ so it follows that $z$ can range from $0$ to $1$. $x² \leq y \leq x$ is equivalent to $y \leq x \leq \sqrt{y}$ and as $y \leq x$ the condition $0 \leq z \leq x$ changes to $0 \leq z \leq y$. So you get

$$\int_\Omega (x+2y) dxdydz = \int_0^1 \int_z^1 \int_y^{\sqrt{y}} (x+2y) dxdydz$$

Comment: hey, thank you for your comment, but it has to be in the original order

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much !